# hexo is unable parse ``` in the middle of a sentence of markdown

Tags: markdown, hexo

I use **hexo** to produce my personal blog website. Everything seems fine. But I find hexo can not parse ```myWidget2```, if words amidst double ``` is in the middle of a sentence, have no line feeds. However, **jekyll** can easily parse them. At the same time, both of them can parse double ``` with `line feeds` to code style. So the key is line feeds.

My hexo version is

`hexo: 3.7.1
hexo-cli: 1.1.0
os: Linux 4.15.0-36-generic linux x64
http_parser: 2.8.0
node: 10.11.0
v8: 6.8.275.32-node.28
uv: 1.23.0
zlib: 1.2.11
ares: 1.14.0
modules: 64
nghttp2: 1.33.0
napi: 3
openssl: 1.1.0i
icu: 62.1
unicode: 11.0
cldr: 33.1
tz: 2018e`

Thank you for your reply! I really need to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot my version of jekyll and hexo. But I find the reason that has difference between hexo and jekyll. If there is no new line using double ```, manifestation in jekyll is right but wrong in hexo. In face, the right form is as follow.

```
hello world
```

There is another way without no line: `hello world` is fine now using double ` instead of ```.

Answer (score 0):

You had better post your markdown code to analysis error, but I use hexo to parse ``` normally, did you forget to use newline between ``` and you content.
Here is a example:

````
    Here is some thing
    ```
    myWidget2
    ```
    Finish
````

If you want to place all in one sentence, maybe replace ``` with `.

Comment: Both hero and Jekyll are able to parse '''good''' with new line among '''. I wanna emphasize that hexo is not working without new line. However, Jekyll is okay. [myWidget1 and mywidget2](http://yhc201.com/blog/2018/09/28/effective-cpp/#3-understand-decltype) is ok in the support of Jekyll.